# Generate noisy image using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, image-manipulation, graphicsmagick

We want to take an input image (`input.png`) and add a noise effect creating `output.png`.

I've tried using GraphicsMagick (using the `gm` module, [here is the link to the docs](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html)):

#### Using a radius

Using `noise(10)` it doesn't create a noisy image, but something that looks more like a painting.

```
const gm = require("gm");

gm("input.png")
    .noise(10)
    .write('output.png', function (err) {
          if (!err) console.log('done');
          console.log(err);
    });
```

#### Using a preset

```
gm("input.png")
        .noise("poisson")
        .write('output.png', function (err) {
              if (!err) console.log('done');
              console.log(err);
        });
```

When using a preset, it's getting there, but I want to control the noise percentage.

What I want to get is something like this, but being able to specify how much noise I want:

> [image]
>
> [Source](https://docs.gimp.org/en/images/filters/examples/noise/taj-rgb-noise.jpg)

Is this possible using GraphicsMagick? Is it possible to do it without installing any binaries?

How to control the noise level?

Comment: to add more, repeat the recipe, to add less, blend the orig with the noise added one.

Comment: oh, and i suggest the workaround because that lib allows only a number _or_ a name

Comment: @dandavis Exactly, but isn't it possible to do the same with another module maybe? Or maybe another GraphicsMagick effect?